# How to validate if a "date and time" string only has a time?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime, time

I have a single string variable that stores what could be a full date or a partial date:

1) Full Date: 12/12/2010 12:33 AM

2) Partial Date: 12:33 AM (no date field only time)

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best approach to parse the string to figure out if the string is missing the date string or not.  The reason is, in my code if the date is missing I will append a default date to the string (such as 1/1/1900).  Keep in mind that the time could be in various formats.

Update - My particular answer to this problem.

As all the "posts" have stated, there are multiple answers to this problem, this is ultimately what I used and hope it can help others*:

```
public DateTime ProcessDateAndTime(string dateString)
{
    string dateAndTimeString = dateString;

    string[] timeFormats = new string[]
    {
        "hh:mm tt", "hh:mm:ss tt",
        "h:mm tt", "h:mm:ss tt", 
        "HH:mm:ss", "HH:mm", "H:mm"
    };
    // check to see if the date string has a time only
    DateTime dateTimeTemp;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, timeFormats,
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTimeTemp))
    {
        // setting date to 01/01/1900
        dateAndTimeString = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).ToShortDateString() + " " + dateString;
    }

    return DateTime.Parse(dateAndTimeString);
}
```

*Note: This method is based on the assumption that there are only a specific amount of time formats used in your application, and that it is guaranteed that a properly formatted date and time, or time only string passed in (pre-validation for removal of garbage text).

Comment: The time could be in various formats or the entire date time string?

Comment: Is this user input in a new application, or data-mining/existing data?  If it is a new application, don't try to solve this - make the user give you data in the right format, and document that you expect it in a particular format.  Or give them GUI controls that give you the right data.

Comment: Matt - The time can be in various formats, ex: 12:55 AM, 12:55:33.
Merlyn - Unfortunately it's with existing data, and not based on a user input.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Use

`Convert.ToDateTime(string value, IFormatProviderProvider provider)`

Since the string comes in different flavors, provide different format providers as needed.

The order could be:

- DateOnly
- Time Only
- DateTime

The convert will throw an format exception if it fails.  If you prefer not to have exceptions, use `Datetime.TryParse` instead as that returns a boolean.

Depending on how the string is represented you could have more than 3 format providers.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to validate string with a RegEx,
BTW, good regexes for `DateTime` validation can be found [here](http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=date%20time)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do this without knowing all possible time formats:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
DateTime time;
DateTime datetime;
bool isTime = DateTime.TryParse(dateString, provider, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out time) 
            && time.Date == DateTime.MinValue.Date
            && DateTime.TryParse(dateString, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out datetime) 
            && datetime.Date != DateTime.MinValue.Date);
```

If the string only has a time then the first TryParse will set the date part to 1/1/0001 or DateTime.MinValue.Date and the second TryParse will set the date part to the current date. This will work unless it is run by Doctor Who after travelling back in time to 1/1/0001.

Comment: I have to say that is a spectacular solution. It served me well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the **best** but it answers your question:

```
    string dateString = "9:53AM";
    if (!dateString.Contains('/')))
    {
        dateString = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + dateString;
    }
```

Comment: `Convert.ToChar("/")`? Why didn't you write just `'/'`?

Comment: Learn something new everyday.. I didn't know you could do that.  I changed it.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: This is not a very good idea if the application should work in multiple regions of the world, since we don't all use '/' to separate dates. 2010-12-12 is a common way to write dates in parts of Europe for an example.

Comment: Right -- there are many reasons why my answer could fail but it did simply answer the question. Bob2Chiv said the time could be in multiple formats but said nothing about the date. I think knowing more details and then writing some regular expressions would probably be the best approach.

Comment: @Matt, I think you might've been referring to the OP: Hans Gruber

Comment: @Bob2Chiv, yes I am sorry about that. Too late to edit and fix it. :/

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the length of the string will be straight-forward and will support multiple formats. A string with a date and time will most certainly be longer than a string with just a time. However, if your input may have times with high precision (12:30:30:50:20 vs 12/11/11 12:30) and low precision this won't work.

This solution is ideal if you don't need to know the value in the string immediately, and only want to add the default date.

If you support times to the second, for instance, a time will have 8 or less characters and a date-time will have 9 or more.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the time can be in various formats (12/24?) it would be best to user several patterns, in some pre-defined order, trying to parse with each and resolving when the first succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
DateTime aTime;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out aTime))
{
    //if the there is no date part in the dateString, date will
    // default to Gregorian 1/1/0001
}
```