# check if date time string contains time

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I have run into an issue. I'm obtaining a date time string from the database and and some of these date time strings does not contain time. But as for the new requirement every date time string should contain the time like so,

1)`1980/10/11 12:00:01`
2)`2010/APRIL/02 17:10:00`
3)`10/02/10 03:30:34`

Date can be in any format followed by the time in `24hr` notation.

I tried to detect the existence of time  via the following code,

```
string timestamp_string = "2013/04/08 17:30";
DateTime timestamp = Convert.ToDateTime(timestamp_string);
string time ="";

if (timestamp_string.Length > 10)
{
    time = timestamp.ToString("hh:mm");
}
else {
    time = "Time not registered";
}

MessageBox.Show(time);
```

But this only works for the No `1)` type timestamps. May I please know how to achieve this task on how to detect if the time element exist in this date time string. Thank you very much :)

**POSSIBLE MATCH**
[How to validate if a "date and time" string only has a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420399/how-to-validate-if-a-date-and-time-string-only-has-a-time)

**INFO** the three answers provided by `Arun Selva Kumar`,`Guru Kara`,`Patipol Paripoonnanonda` are all correct and checks for the time and serves my purpose. But I select `Guru Kara`s answer solely on ease of use and for the explanation he has given. Thank you very much :) very much appreciated all of you :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The date time components [TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) is what you need.

MSDN says *"Unlike the Date property, which returns a DateTime value that represents a date without its time component, the TimeOfDay property returns a TimeSpan value that represents a DateTime value's time component."*

Here is an example with consideration of all your scenarios.
Since you are sure of the format you can use `DateTime.Parse` else please use `DateTime.TryParse`

```
var dateTime1 = System.DateTime.Parse("1980/10/11 12:00:00");
var dateTime2 = System.DateTime.Parse("2010/APRIL/02 17:10:00");
var dateTime3 = System.DateTime.Parse("10/02/10 03:30:34");
var dateTime4 = System.DateTime.Parse("02/20/10");

if (dateTime1.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("1980/10/11 12:00:00 - does not have Time");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("1980/10/11 12:00:00 - has Time");
}

if (dateTime2.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("2010/APRIL/02 17:10:00 - does not have Time");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("2010/APRIL/02 17:10:00 - Has Time");
}

if (dateTime3.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("10/02/10 03:30:34 - does not have Time");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("10/02/10 03:30:34 - Has Time");
}

if (dateTime4.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("02/20/10 - does not have Time");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("02/20/10 - Has Time");
}
```

Comment: hey thank you for the reply :) i will go thru ths n post back :)

Comment: -1: This method fails on any datetime string with a specified time of midnight; e.g. for "2015-02-26T00:00" I expect a result of "Has Time", but System.DateTime.Parse("2015-02-26T00:00").TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds evaluates to 0.0.

Comment: In the first sentence, the name of the method is spelled wrong.  I tried to edit it, but the stackoverflow UI says that edits must be at least six characters.  Also, I agree with Kasper van den Berg that this answer does not meet the requirements.

Comment: I agree with Kasper.  This doesn't account for midnight being specified as a valid time.

Comment: I have to disagree - If total seconds is 0, then you know in fact the time would be midnight right?

Comment: I agree with Kasper as well. If the time is 00:00, TotalSeconds will give value 0. Which would be a indicator that it has no time attribute, while it certainly has.

Answer (score 9):

Try this,

```
DateTime myDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(inputString, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate))
{
    //String has Date and Time
}
else
{
    //String has only Date Portion    
}
```

You can try using other format specifiers as listed here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: hey thanx for the reply :) i will try this out n post  back :)

Comment: If the string is not a date, your else will give wrong answer. You need use another DateTime.TryParseExact for just date format.

Comment: hey i tried this but it always give the error message ? do you knwo y??
`string a = "08/04/2013 17:34:00";
            
            DateTime myDate;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(a, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Correct");
                //String has Date and Time
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
                //String has only Date Portion    
            }`

Comment: @Hasitha you are getting Error cos, the format specifier you had given is wrong "hh" denotes hours in 12 hours format, use HH for the format specified.  Kindly refer the link I had provided for the list of formats for datetime!

Answer (score 6):

Combining the answers of [Guru Kara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/386161/guru-kara) and [Patipol Paripoonnanonda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2236933/patipol-paripoonnanonda) with the .net globalisation API results in:

```cs
bool HasExplicitTime(DateTime parsedTimestamp, string str_timestamp)
{
    string[] dateTimeSeparators = { "T", " ", "@" };
    string[] timeSeparators = {
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator,
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator,
        ":"};

    if (parsedTimestamp.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds != 0)
        return true;

    string[] dateOrTimeParts = str_timestamp.Split(
            dateTimeSeparators,
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    bool hasTimePart = dateOrTimeParts.Any(part =>
            part.Split(
                    timeSeparators,
                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length > 1);
    return hasTimePart;
}
```

This approach:

- detects explicit midnight times (e.g. "2015-02-26T00:00");
- only searches the string when `TimeOfDay` indicates midnight or no explicit time; and
- finds explicit midnight times in local format and any non midnight time in any format that .net can parse.

Limitations:

- explicit midnight times in non culture local format are not detected;
- explicit midnight times with less than two parts are not detected; and
- less simple and elegant than the approaches of Guru Kara and Patipol Paripoonnanonda.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'm going with for now.  It may not be perfect, but likely better than considering any 12am datetime as not having a time.  The premise is that if I tack a full time specification on the end it will parse if it's just a date but fail if it already has a time component.

I had to make the assumption that there's not some valid, date/time that has 7 non-white-space characters or less.  It appears that "1980/10" parses, but not "1980/10 01:01:01.001".

I've included various test cases.  Feel free to add your own and let me know if they fail.

```
public static bool IsValidDateTime(this string dateString, bool requireTime = false)
{
    DateTime outDate;
    if(!DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out outDate)) return false;

    if (!requireTime) return true;
    else
    {
        return Regex.Replace(dateString, @"\s", "").Length > 7 
&& !DateTime.TryParse(dateString + " 01:01:01.001", out outDate);
    }
}

public void DateTest()
{
    var withTimes = new[]{
    "1980/10/11 01:01:01.001",
    "02/01/1980 01:01:01.001",
    "1980-01-01 01:01:01.001",
    "1980/10/11 00:00",
    "1980/10/11 1pm",
    "1980-01-01 00:00:00"};

    //Make sure our ones with time pass both tests
    foreach(var date in withTimes){
        Assert.IsTrue(date.IsValidDateTime(), String.Format("date: {0} isn't valid.", date));
        Assert.IsTrue(date.IsValidDateTime(true), String.Format("date: {0} does have time.", date));
    }

    var withoutTimes = new[]{
    "1980/10/11",
    "1980/10",
    "1980/10 ",
    "10/1980",
    "1980 01",
    "1980/10/11 ",
    "02/01/1980",
    "1980-01-01"};

    //Make sure our ones without time pass the first and fail the second
    foreach (var date in withoutTimes)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(date.IsValidDateTime(), String.Format("date: {0} isn't valid.", date));
        Assert.IsFalse(date.IsValidDateTime(true), String.Format("date: {0} doesn't have time.", date) );
    }

    var bogusTimes = new[]{
    "1980",
    "1980 01:01",
    "80 01:01",
    "1980T01",
    "80T01:01",
    "1980-01-01T01",
    };

    //Make sure our ones without time pass the first and fail the second
    foreach (var date in bogusTimes)
    {
        DateTime parsedDate;
        DateTime.TryParse(date, out parsedDate);
        Assert.IsFalse(date.IsValidDateTime(), String.Format("date: {0} is valid. {1}", date, parsedDate));
        Assert.IsFalse(date.IsValidDateTime(true), String.Format("date: {0} is valid. {1}", date, parsedDate));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for your use case:

bool noTime = _datetimevalue.TimeOfDay.Ticks == 0;

If no time component exists in the DateTime instance, Ticks will be 0.

Answer (score -1):

Date and time are always separated by a space bar. The easiest way would be:

```
if (timestamp_string.Split(' ').Length == 2)
{
    // timestamp_string has both date and time
}
else
{
    // timestamp_string only has the date
}
```

This code assumes the date always exists.

If you want take it further (in case the date does not exist), you can do:

```
if (timestamp_string.Split(' ')
                    .Select(item => item.Split(':').Length > 1)
                    .Any(item => item))
{
    // this would work for any string format that contains date, for example:
    // 2012/APRIL/03 12:00:05 -> this would work
    // 2013/04/05 09:00:01 -> this would work
    // 08:50:45 2013/01/01 -> this would also work
    // 08:50:50 -> this would also work
}
else
{
    // no date in the timestamp_string at all
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey thanx for the reply i will check this and post back :)

Comment: Have you had a chance to try it? Please let me know.

Comment: hey..hi..sorry for the delay..i selected an answer and I explained the reason why in the question itself.. many thanks for help :) very much appreciated.

Comment: Date time strings sometimes use 'T' (e.g. dates in ISO 8601 standard format) or '@' ; edited to improve

Comment: As @KaspervandenBerg pointed out, not all formats have a space between the date and the time. And the format could also have a space even if there is no time, e.g. "Jun 29, 2017". If you are able to get a comprehensive list of all date/time formats used in your database, you might be able to use this trick. But it sounds like that's not the case.

Comment: As others have noted assuming a space will be a reliable delimiter could get you into trouble down the road, ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601