# C# date part of dateTime extension property

Tags: c#

I have extension method on DateTime class:

```
public static DateTime? SafeConvertToDateTime(this string value, bool dateOnly)
{
    DateTime parsedDateTime;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out parsedDateTime))
    {
        return DateTime.SpecifyKind(parsedDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    } else {
        return new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }
}
```

If "dateOnly=true" i should return Datetime with only Date property and all conversions later on client (to local or utc) should be skipped if there is DateTime with only Date.
But how can i know that this DateTime holds only Date(since time can be valid as 0)? 
I could add extension property (dateOnly), but as I know, I can't add extension property in C#, only methods?
Can I use some existing property of Datetime to tell, there is only date which should be consider later in code?

Comment: Why not just use DateTime.Date is your later code?  If the code shouldn't depend on the time portion, then make sure it only references the date part.

Comment: This isn't an extension method on the DateTime class, this is an extension to the string class.

Comment: If you `return DateTime.Date;`, then only the Date part will be returned, time parts will be = 0

Comment: If you have a `DateTime` instance and you want to get only the date there is a property called `Date` which will zero out the time to midnight. Also why return a nullable `DateTime?` if you always return a `DateTime` instance? You should probably return null in the `else` part of your `if`. Finally with `c#7` you can inline the `TryParse(value, out parsedDateTime)` as `TryParse(value, out DateTime parsedDateTime)`

Comment: Sorry, it is extension method of string class.
I must somehow define in DateTime that you should look only Date part of it.

Comment: You would need to know the exact format of the date or date time being passed (so 2 formats).

Comment: Igor, you mean that if Date only, I can use format like "yyyyMMdd" if with time, than "MMddyyyy" and then on client side check with TryParse, which format is valid and based on that know if there is datetime with only date?

Answer (score 0):

> But how can i know that this DateTime holds only Date(since time can
>   be valid as 0)?

There is no way to achieve this using the existing DateTime class - since you won't be able to distinguish a 'date' vs a 'datetime that happens to be at midnight'. They will look exactly the same.

[The Date type](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/6c4cf54689003a5d8633370d3d14f2244237b9b7/src/System.Time/System/DateTimeExtensions.cs) may be of interest - but given DateTime and Date are different types you'll need to alter your code to handle both types. [Noda's LocalDate](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/NodaTime.LocalDate.html) may also be of interest.

If you decide to use the Date type, you could create a wrapper class that contains *either* a date or a datetime, and pass it around as needed:

```
public class DateWithOrWithoutTime
{
    public Date? DateWithoutTime { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? DateWithTime { get; private set; }

    public DateWithOrWithoutTime(Date dateToSet)
    {
        DateWithoutTime = dateToSet;
    }
    public DateWithOrWithoutTime(DateTime dateTimeToSet)
    {
        DateWithTime = dateTimeToSet;
    }

    public bool IsDate()
    {
        return DateWithoutTime != null;
    }

    public bool IsDateTime()
    {
        return DateWithTime != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Simon Does that do what you are expecting? Or is there different functionality that you need?

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893339/check-if-date-time-string-contains-time) on how to check if a datetime string contains a time. You Need to use the `TimeOfDay` property.

Comment: if you found another post which answers current question, use duplicate flag or vote to close as duplicate. if unsure post a comment. don't post link to another question as an answer.